Elastic Search Regex are not working as expected for if in data has some space in between of the words
have go the problem in making Elasticsearch regex work. I have a document that looks like this:
{"content": "My name is Akesh Jadhav."}
I have tried the following regex "Akesh\sJadhav" to match the Akesh Jadhav with the regex query. I use a keyword field but this regex doesn't work. Can you suggest me correct regex to get my result and one thing I want to perform this search with regex only.
Tried with \s, and \s and \\s also, [\s], [\s].
But did't work that.

Can you share the code / query that you are using for the search?

Can you try regx as Akesh[ ]?Jadhav

This is my query, trying to do regex search with space in between the word
POST 481046270_mails/_search
{
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"term": {
"isEmbedded": {
"value": false
}
}
},
{
"bool": {
"should": [
{
"regexp": {
"hTMLBody.not_analyzed": {
"value": "malicious\sip"
}
}
}
]
}
}
]
}
}
}

Is there a single space? Or are there 1 or more spaces? For the latter you could try \\s+ Was the field type always a keyword? What if you first search with only the query for the regexp?

trying with single space, and tried \s+, but still not matching using regexp

Never used the regexp function before but when trying it with my elasticsearch db the regexp only works when the value matches the complete field value:
{ "query": 
  { "bool": { "must": [ 
     { "term": { "isEmbedded": { "value": false } } }, 
     { "bool": { "should": [ 
         { "regexp": { "hTMLBody.not_analyzed": 
                         { "value": ".*malicious\\s+ip.*" } } } 
       ] } } 
    ] }} 
}

About partial text search maybe this can be interesting as well: How do I do a partial match in Elasticsearch?
